# Observer design pattern in Yii 1.1.16, attaching event handlers and rising events

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

In Yii 1.1.16 [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is implemented using *events & behaivours* (events can be shared between all components that extends [CComponents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent)). I have following models:

> 1. **User.php** (see below)
> 2. **Work.php** (see below)
> 3. **Activity.php**

what I want to accomplish is following:
lets say in **DefaultController:**

```
<?php
  public function actionExampleWork()
  {
    $work = new Work();
    $work->description = 'some random description';
    $work->created_at = new CDbException('NOW()');
    $work->user_id = 1;

    //$work->attach() INVOKE EVENT that will be handled by all models which listen to this event

    $work->save();
 }
 public function actionExampleUser()
 {
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = 'foo@example.com';
    $user->username = 'example';
    $user->password = '123';

    //$user->attach( something ) invoke Event that should be handled only by Activity model

    $user-> save();
 }

?>
```

actually I have saw lot of examples Yii doing related things, but so far no success on finding answer that fit's my needs :(

- **Is this possible in Yii?**
- **How can I implement this?**
- **Is there an alternatives (except manually handling method calls in controller actions)? **

> **User.php**

```
<?php class User extends CActiveRecord
{
public function tableName()
{
    //@return string the associated database table name
};

public function rules()
{
    //@return array validation rules for model attributes.
};

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'works' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Works', 'user_id'],
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    //@return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
}

public function search()
{
    //@return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
    // based on the search/filter conditions.
}
public function updateLastActivity($user_id, $activity_type){

   $user = $user->model()->findByPk($user_id);//find user
   $user->activity_type = $activity_type;
   $user->last_action = new CDbExpression('NOW()');//update DB column
   $user->save; //save user

}
} ?>
```

> **Work.php**

```
<?php

class Work extends CActiveRecord
{
public function tableName()
{
    //@return string the associated database table name
}

public function rules()
{
    //@return array validation rules for model attributes.
}

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'],
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    //@return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
}

public function search()
{
    //@return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
    // based on the search/filter conditions.
}


?>
```

Comment: this should help you http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an observer class for your scenario.

**Using Built in Event Handlers**
The Yii model class has a few built in functions that you can overwrite in your class.

Have a look at the official documentation for CActiveRecord for more detaiils.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord
*HINT: Search for beforeXXXX, afterXXXX, onXXXXX*

As an example, here is my pre-persist handler for my user model.

```
    /**
 * Runs just before the models save method is invoked. It provides a change to
 * ...further prepare the data for saving. The CActiveRecord (parent class)
 * ...beforeSave is called to process any raised events.
 *
 * @param <none> <none>
 * @return boolean the decision to continue the save or not.
 *
 * @access public
 */

public function beforeSave() {
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Some scenarios only require certain fields to be updated. We handle
    // ...this separately.
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_LOGIN)
{
    /** Login scenario */
    $this->last_login = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
}

if ($this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_ACTIVATION)
{
    /** Account activation scenario */

    if ($this->activation_status == 'activated')
    {
        $this->activation_code = '';
        $this->status          = 'active';
        $this->activation_time = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    }
}

if ( ($this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_CHANGE_PASSWORD) ||
     ($this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_REGISTER) ||
     ($this->scenario == 'insert') ||
     ($this->scenario == 'update')
   )
{
    /** Password change scenario */

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Encrypt the password. Only do this if the password is set
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($this->password) && (!empty($this->password)))
    {
        $this->password    =  CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($this->password);

    }
}


/** All other scenarios */

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Set the create time and user for new records
// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($this->isNewRecord) {
    $this->created_time = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    $this->created_by   = '1';  // Special case for not logged in user
    $this->modified_by  = '1';
}
else
{
    $this->modified_by   = isset(Yii::app()->user->id)?Yii::app()->user->id:1;
}

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The modified log details is set for record creation and update
// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$this->modified_time = new CDbExpression('NOW()');

return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Notice that I have full access to the record BEFORE the save happens (ie. no access to primary-key when a new record is being processed.

Look out also for built in scenarios 'insert' and 'update'.

Note also that I invoke the parent beforeSave before exiting to cascade events in the parents.

**Using Custom Events**

You can create custom events.

Create an event class eg. protected/components/Newuser.php:

```
class NewUser extends CModelEvent{
    public $userRecord;
}
```

Then in your controller

```
$userModel->attachEventHandler('onNewUser',newuserEventHandler);

function newuserEventHandler($event){
      // Add custom handling code here 
      do_some_things_here($event->new, $event->id);
    }
```

In your model, you need to raise the event

```
$event=new NewUserEvent;
// Add custom data to event.
$event->new=$this->isNewRecord;
$event->order=$this->id;
$this->raiseEvent('onNewUser',$event);
```

Comment: This makes it more clear, but still. How Yii will understand the fact that if Event in User model has been invoked, than it needs to execute other model's methods ?

Comment: **Problem is** that: I want to invoke **global event** in `User.php` model, that will be handled in all models (`Works.php` ...`ExampleModel.php`... etc. ), which have specific method (handleGlobalEvent  raised from `User.php` model), that corresponds to this event. Still confused :(

Comment: I don;t think the Yii event model is mature enough to handle this scenario. Still you can create custom events, but you have to manually raise the events. You will have to manage the unit of work manually. I updated my response to show how to create custom event.

Comment: You can create a class in components that extends CActiveRecord and change your model to extend that class. Your new parent class can contain the event handled that will be available to be invoked for all models.